# Are there any standards to be followed while writing a jquery Plugin?

Tags: jquery, plugins

I'm new to open source development and i love to write jquery plugins and share with people, so i have few questions!

1. Should i follow some sort of standards while developing an open source jquery plugin?
2. Are there any online tools to validate if my plugin is up to those standards?

I tried to google about the same and couldn't find exact answer for it. So if any other suggestions related to this topic are more appreciated.

please pardon me if my doubts are silly as i mention earlier i'm a newbie. Thanks

Comment: You can find on Goog **jQuery plugins boilerplate** and also read a bit more about http://learn.jquery.com/plugins/basic-plugin-creation/ just to get started.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

jQuery site has an excellent tutorial and the best practices are also discussed.

http://learn.jquery.com/plugins/basic-plugin-creation/

Comment: their tutorials are totally basic. They're missing some great uses of their own closures, mudules and plugin patterns. More on that topic with examples on Google or by just inspecting good plugins codes and finding references online.

Comment: @Selvaraj M A, Thanks for you answer but my question is specific to developing a open source jQuery plugin so that it must be accepted by wide range of audience. Hope i'm clear with my point now :)

Comment: @juno, have you read what they say about the best practices? you didn't. It's all there: http://learn.jquery.com/plugins/advanced-plugin-concepts/#remember-it-39-s-a-compromise :) short and simple. It's a compromise in plugin flexibility and size.

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan, Thanks and +1 for final simple answer. But i would still like to know if there are any online tools which can tell me how good my plugin is or it can suggest me some improvement if possible

Comment: @Juno, there's not such intelligent beast out there. The plugin is good if allows a user to have accessible lots of options or even `extend()` the plugin at will. Look at Google: **jQuery Plugin Bolierplate** there's nice templates to start with your own plugin, every line is well commented. To test you JS than you can go to jslint.com and see if there's issues with it. Good luck with your plugin and +1 for joining OSource.

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan, Thanks for your suggestions and i'm good to go now :). can check my first plugin [here](http://jsever.blogspot.in/) and can suggest me improvements. Really needs experts advice's :)